# If a function is quasiconcave on a curve, does it also have to be quasiconcave on a convex set?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Function $f(x,y)$ is continuous increasing on both dimensions. $f(x,y)$ is locally strictly quasiconcave on a non-linear curve $\gamma\subset\mathbb R$ (i.e. $\{(x,y)|f(x,y)=\lambda\}\cap \gamma$ is convex to origin $\forall\lambda$).

Does this implies that $f(x,y)$ must be also quasiconcave on some convex subset of $\mathbb R$?

Strictly qusiconcave means $f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) b))<\max\{f(a),f(b)\} \ \forall a,b\in\mathbb R^2$, and $\lambda\in(0,1)$

or, alternatively, $C=\{a\in\mathbb R^2|f(a)\geq\lambda\}$ is a strictly convex set $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb R$

Comment: How are you defining "strictly quasiconcave on a curve"? I'm almost positive the answer is "no," but I'd like to make sure I'm reading your question correctly.

Comment: @MichaelLee Sorry, $f$ has to be continuously increasing. I edited it out last time but it was not intented.

Comment: And what does it mean for a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be increasing? There isn't an obvious order on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Also, this still doesn't clarify what it means for $f(x, y)$ to be strictly quasiconcave on a curve $\gamma : [0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$. Is it that $f\circ \gamma$ is strictly quasiconcave on $[0, 1]$? Or is it that $f(\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b) < \max(f(a), f(b))$ for all $a$ and $b$ on $\gamma$? In the latter, of course, $\lambda a+(1-\lambda)b$ might not be on $\gamma$ if $\gamma$ is not linear.

Comment: @MichaelLee Updated. Though I think it is better to rephrase this question to another more clearly defined question.